# Can anyone tell me why this setinterval keeps getting shorter and short

Tags: reactjs

This setinterval fires as expected until it gets to the last string in the array and im not sure why

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setwho(headerPhrases[
                Math.floor(Math.random() * headerPhrases.length)
                ])
        console.log('Change')
        }, [count])

        setInterval(() => {
            setcount(count + 1)

        }, 5000);
```

It fires faster and faster every time it runs i used the same logic in  another app and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of your interval, on every render you create a new interval when the component re-renders. Implement your interval as a hook, like so:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef
} = React;

// Hook implementation for using setInterval()
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

// You may use hook `useInterval()` like: 
function Counter() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <h1 > Interval counter: {
    count
  } < /h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```